# how do i add +1 to a label each time a button is clicked?

Tags: c#, asp.net, button, label

protected void btnsubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)

```
    {
        int result;
        result=Convert.ToInt32(lblresult.Text);

    }
```

this is all I have so far (just the variable)

Comment: I would take the time to revisit the `C# Basics Tutorial` lots of free examples online you could have also found the solution in less than a second with a simple google search.

Answer (score 2):

Convert lblStart.Text value to int every time and assign it to i. Then increase i.

```
protected void btnsubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
    i =   Int32.Parse(lblStart.Text);
    i++; 
    lblStart.Text = i.ToString();
 }
```